# Spring-boot security 3 - Thymeleaf issue with sec:authentication="principal.authorities"

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

When upgrading my project from Spring-boot 2 > 3 + creating a  native image I am getting the below issue. When I compile it into a jar and run it in JVM it works fine and I can see [ROLE_USER]

Get user from the DB and add to page.

```java
 @GetMapping("/user")
    public String registration(Authentication authentication, Model model) {
        UserDto user = userDetails.getUserDetails(authentication.getName());
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        return "user";
    }
```

User.html

```xml
 <div sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()" sec:authentication="principal.authorities"></div>
```

{
2023-01-14T16:34:40.661Z ERROR 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             : [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-4] Exception processing template "user": Error retrieving value for property "principal.authorities" of authentication object of class org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken (template: "user" - line 32, col 52)

org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error retrieving value for property "principal.authorities" of authentication object of class org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken (template: "user" - line 32, col 52)
at org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity6.auth.AuthUtils.getAuthenticationProperty(AuthUtils.java:151) ~[na:na]
at org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity6.dialect.processor.AuthenticationAttrProcessor.doProcess(AuthenticationAttrProcessor.java:67) ~[na:na]
at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:74) ~[com.jackbourner.reactthymeleaf.ReactThymeleafApplication:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95) ~[com.jackbourner.reactthymeleaf.ReactThymeleafApplication:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:633) ~[na:na]
at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleOpenElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1314) ~[na:na]
at org.thymeleaf.engine.OpenElementTag.beHandled(OpenElementTag.java:205) ~[na:na]
at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateModel.process(TemplateModel.java:136) ~[com.jackbourner.reactthymeleaf.ReactThymeleafApplication:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:661) ~[na:na]
at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1103) ~[com.jackbourner.reactthymeleaf.ReactThymeleafApplication:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1077) ~[com.jackbourner.reactthymeleaf.ReactThymeleafApplication:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.spring6.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:372) ~[com.jackbourner.reactthymeleaf.ReactThymeleafApplication:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.spring6.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:192) ~[com.jackbourner.reactthymeleaf.ReactThymeleafApplication:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1414) ~[com.jackbourner.reactthymeleaf.ReactThymeleafApplication:6.0.3]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1158) ~[com.jackbourner.reactthymeleaf.ReactThymeleafApplication:6.0.3]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1097) ~[com.jackbourner.reactthymeleaf.ReactThymeleafApplication:6.0.3]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:973) ~[com.jackbourner.reactthymeleaf.ReactThymeleafApplication:6.0.3]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1010) ~[com.jackbourner.reactthymeleaf.ReactThymeleafApplication:6.0.3]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:902) ~[com.jackbourner.reactthymeleaf.ReactThymeleafApplication:6.0.3]
at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:705) ~[com.jackbourner.reactthymeleaf.ReactThymeleafApplication:6.0]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:884) ~[com.jackbourner.reactthymeleaf.ReactThymeleafApplication:6.0.3]
at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:814) ~[com.jackbourner.reactthymeleaf.ReactThymeleafApplication:6.0]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:223) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[com.jackbourner.reactthymeleaf.ReactThymeleafApplication:10.1.4]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.lambda$doFilterInternal$3(FilterChainProxy.java:231) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$FilterObservation$SimpleFilterObservation.lambda$wrap$1(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:399) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$AroundFilterObservation$SimpleAroundFilterObservation.lambda$wrap$1(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:297) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator.lambda$wrapSecured$0(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:79) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:125) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:100) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:186) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:173) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:186) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:173) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:186) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:173) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:186) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:173) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:186) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:173) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:227) ~[com.jackbourner.reactthymeleaf.ReactThymeleafApplication:6.0.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:221) ~[com.jackbourner.reactthymeleaf.ReactThymeleafApplication:6.0.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:186) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:173) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:186) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:173) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:116) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[com.jackbourner.reactthymeleaf.ReactThymeleafApplication:6.0.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:186) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:173) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[com.jackbourner.reactthymeleaf.ReactThymeleafApplication:6.0.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:186) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:173) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:186) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:173) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[com.jackbourner.reactthymeleaf.ReactThymeleafApplication:6.0.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:186) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:173) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[com.jackbourner.reactthymeleaf.ReactThymeleafApplication:6.0.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:186) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$AroundFilterObservation$SimpleAroundFilterObservation.lambda$wrap$0(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:280) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:170) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:351) ~[com.jackbourner.reactthymeleaf.ReactThymeleafApplication:6.0.3]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267) ~[com.jackbourner.reactthymeleaf.ReactThymeleafApplication:6.0.3]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[com.jackbourner.reactthymeleaf.ReactThymeleafApplication:6.0.3]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[com.jackbourner.reactthymeleaf.ReactThymeleafApplication:6.0.3]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[com.jackbourner.reactthymeleaf.ReactThymeleafApplication:6.0.3]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[com.jackbourner.reactthymeleaf.ReactThymeleafApplication:6.0.3]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.web.filter.ServerHttpObservationFilter.doFilterInternal(ServerHttpObservationFilter.java:109) ~[com.jackbourner.reactthymeleaf.ReactThymeleafApplication:6.0.3]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[com.jackbourner.reactthymeleaf.ReactThymeleafApplication:6.0.3]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[com.jackbourner.reactthymeleaf.ReactThymeleafApplication:6.0.3]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[com.jackbourner.reactthymeleaf.ReactThymeleafApplication:6.0.3]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:177) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[com.jackbourner.reactthymeleaf.ReactThymeleafApplication:10.1.4]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:119) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[com.jackbourner.reactthymeleaf.ReactThymeleafApplication:10.1.4]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:400) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[com.jackbourner.reactthymeleaf.ReactThymeleafApplication:10.1.4]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:859) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1734) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[com.jackbourner.reactthymeleaf.ReactThymeleafApplication:10.1.4]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[na:na]
at java.base@17.0.5/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[com.jackbourner.reactthymeleaf.ReactThymeleafApplication:na]
at com.oracle.svm.core.thread.PlatformThreads.threadStartRoutine(PlatformThreads.java:775) ~[com.jackbourner.reactthymeleaf.ReactThymeleafApplication:na]
at com.oracle.svm.core.posix.thread.PosixPlatformThreads.pthreadStartRoutine(PosixPlatformThreads.java:203) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'principal.authorities' of bean class [org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken]: Bean property 'principal.authorities' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:626) ~[com.jackbourner.reactthymeleaf.ReactThymeleafApplication:6.0.3]
at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:616) ~[com.jackbourner.reactthymeleaf.ReactThymeleafApplication:6.0.3]
at org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity6.auth.AuthUtils.getAuthenticationProperty(AuthUtils.java:137) ~[na:na]
... 129 common frames omitted

2023-01-14T16:34:40.677Z ERROR 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error retrieving value for property "principal.authorities" of authentication object of class org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken (template: "user" - line 32, col 52)] with root cause

org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'principal.authorities' of bean class [org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken]: Bean property 'principal.authorities' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
}

Comment: What version of boot are you bumping from. Iv the exact same issue in boot version 2.6.12. have you found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Use the authorities from the authentication, not the principal. You have no guarantees in regard to the principal class and properties.

Example:

```
 <span sec:authentication="authorities">
```

The Authentication interface guarantees the authorities property.